# Іншомовні абревіатури

Tags: власні-назви, іншомовні-слова, скорочення

Чому **UN** (United Nations) перекладається як **ООН** (Організація об'єднаних націй)?

Зате **NATO** (North Atlantic Treaty Organization) як **НАТО** (хоча **О**рганіза́ція **П**івнічноатлантичного **д**о́говору)?

Як правильно перекладати абревіатури? Наприклад компанія **[TED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TED_(conference))**. Яким способом буде краще перекласти її назву?

Answer (score 3):

[Уривок](https://studfile.net/preview/1588475/page:10/) з [Карабан В. І. «Переклад англійської наукової і технічної літератури» с. 449–450](//books.google.com/books?id=zAzWCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA450&dq=%22%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22) і [Карабан В. І. «Переклад англійської наукової і технічної літератури: Граматичні труднощі» с. 509–511](//books.google.com/books?id=6cZwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA510&dq=%22%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22):

> …Способи їхньої передачі на цільову мову…:
>
> 1. Переклад відповідним скороченням: MPS (main propulsion sys­tem) — ГРУ (головна рушійна установка), MTF (modulation transfer system) — ФПМ (функція передачі модуляції), PC (personal computer) — ПК (персо­нальний комп'ютер), Мх (maxwell) — Мкс (максвел), NMR (nuclear magnetic resonance) — ЯМР (ядерний магнітний резонанс), МІС (microwave integrated circuit) — НВЧ ІМ (інтегрована мережа надвисокої частоти), Mhz (megahertz) — Мгц (мегагерц), DTL (diode transistor logic) — ДТЛ (діодно-транзисторна логіка), ESP (electrostatic precipitator) — ЕФ (електрофільтр).
>
>    Даний спосіб перекладу передбачає використання існуючої у мові перекладу абревіатури-відповідника або створення її (у випадку авторсь­ких скорочень). Слід зазначити, що у мові перекладу скорочення можу бути побудованим за тією ж моделлю, що й у мові оригіналу (наприклад, ABE — ПРД «повітряно-реактивний двигун»), або за іншою моделлю (наприклад, coul — Кл «кулон»; blstg pwd — ВР «вибухова речовина»). Такі скорочення звичайно зафіксовані у словниках скорочень.
> 2. <…>
> 3. Транскодування (транскрибування або транслітерування) ско­рочення: ICAO (International Civil Aviation Organization) — ІКАО (Міжна­родна організація цивільної авіації), NATO (North Atlantic Treaty Organiza­tion) — HATO, IMCO (Intergovernmental Maritime Consulting Organization) — ІМКО (Міжнародна морська консультативна організація), IUPAC (Interna­tional Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry) — ІЮПАК (Міжнародний союз теоретичної і прикладної хімії).
>
>    **Якоїсь певної закономірності щодо вибору між транскодуванням та перекладом повних форм відповідних скорочень, очевидно, немає, однак слід зауважити, що існує тенденція до транскодування англійських широко вживаних скорочень, що позначають важливі міжнародні організації, аген­тства, об'єднання, корпорації тощо**: UPI (United Press International) — аген­тство ЮПІ, GATT — ГАТТ, Benelux — Бенілюкс.
>
>    Транскодуються й деякі інші скорочення та складноскорочені слова: teflon — тефлон, maser — мазер, opcode — опкод (операційний код), pixel (picture element) — піксел (елемент відображення), Internet — Інтернет, vocoder (voice coder) — вокодер, INMARSAT (International Maritime Satellite Organization) — IHMAPCAT.
> 4. <…>

Отже принаймні один автор вважає, що певної закономірності немає (однак нині тяжіють до транскодування).

Comment: Тобто єдиного "офіційного" способу поки не існує, так?

Comment: @int_ua, наскільки я знаю — так.

Answer (score 2):

Ви будете певно зустрічати суперечливі думки з цього приводу.

Європейську Унію ми чомусь називаємо ЄС, здається, загальновживаність в даному випадку діє саме таким чином.

Я би відштовхувався від впізнаваності - якщо компанія TED впізнавана саме за такою абревіатурою латиницею, то і вживати треба саме цю абревіатуру.

Інакшою ознакою може бути винесення абревіатури на логотип або знак для товарів і послуг, або в скорочене найменування юридичної особи, політичної партії, громадської організації, тощо.

Компанія TED - яскравий приклад - її знають саме за абревіатурою винесеною на логотип, навіть якщо цей логотип не зареєстрований жодним чином. Я впевнений, що проведене сьогодні опитування з єдиним питанням: що є логотипом компанії TED, дасть близький до ста відсотків результат - три великі червоні букви TED.

Якщо ж Ви маєте власну думку щодо певної абревіатури і її написання, введіть правило для свого тексту: Європейська Унія (далі по тексту ЄУ); і пояснювати більше нічого не треба.

Comment: @Yola, чому ж, по-моєму, думки/приклади, що стосуються теми (підтверджують погляди автора про те, як треба чи не треба передавати абревіатури), цілком доречні. Єдине що — не варто висувати такі незвичні твердження (що ЄС — росіянізм) без обґрунтування (от якби автор навів джерела/обґрунтування того, що ЄС — росіянізм, була б інша справа).

Comment: RomAMO, мені подобається ідея передавати European Union як Європейська Унія ([унія](http://sum.in.ua/s/unija), здається, доречне слово; і зберігається схожіть з оригінальною абревіатурою). Але водночас Європейський [Союз](http://sum.in.ua/s/sojuz) я вважаю цілком прийнятною назвою (і вона усталеніша). З тим, що ЄС — росіянізм, я незгоден.

Comment: @Yola, я то не до холівару, просто перше що спало на думку в якості прикладу

Comment: @Sasha, і я про те, що вона загальновживана

Comment: @Yola, забрав взагалі, щоб не лізло в очі