# У якому роді узгоджується COVID-19?

Tags: переклад, запозичені-слова, скорочення, рід, узгодження-слів

Звучить, як чоловічий рід, але чи це так?

Питання натхненне [публікацією](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-covid-19-ou-la-covid-19) [Французької Академії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F) з цим запитанням щодо французької мови.

Comment: Не дуже [відповідь](https://www.facebook.com/inmo.org.ua/posts/1605921659575783) від ІМ імені O.O.Потебні НАНУ.

Answer (score 3):

Чоловічого.

#### Теорія

Іменник *ковід* закінчується на твердий приголосний [д], що має м'який відповідник [д']. Такі іменники можуть:

- належати до 2-ї відміни — лише якщо вони чоловічого роду (*карбід*, *поїзд* тощо);
- бути зовсім невідмінованими — теоретично будь-якого роду (зокрема застосовується до іноземних жіночих імен — *Долорес*, *Маргарет* тощо).

Але українська мова тяжіє до відмінювання іменників. І навіть якщо писати латиницею й не відмінювати, воно буде сприйматися в тому ж роді, що й подібні іменники на *-ід*.

#### Узус

> Після цих «інтелектуальних перлів» думаєш: «Можливо **той ковід** є рятівним вірусом, який вилікує, нарешті, націю від дебілів? Нехай собі ходять, інфікуються». //http://www.mukachevo.net/ua/news/view/1112653
>
> В Пасічній **той ковід** до дупи. //https://starosynjavska-gromada.gov.ua/news/1585151072/
>
> Чи так вже страшний **той ковід** і чи потрібен карантин? //https://tydyvy.com/video/DylGIVU
>
> Чи такий страшний **той COVID-19**? //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBzI9sGWGEA
>
> Хай **той COVID-19** тільки спробує — точно поламає свої короназуби об наш оптимізм! //https://www.volyn.com.ua/news/151496-lisapetnyi-batalion-dav-lupnia-koronavirusu-samohonom-seksom-chasnykom-tsybuleiu-i-zvisno-humorom-video
>
> Навколо більше місяця всі тільки й говорять про **той Covid-19**, стараються сховатися від нього і вберегтись, а я лише хочу жити далі! //https://www.volynnews.com/news/all/ya-tsoho-boiavsia-naybilshe-stan-onkokhvoroho-luchanyna-pohirshyvsia-potribna-vysokodozna-khimiia/
>
> І, чомусь, нікого не насторожив той факт, що тисячі вчених на усій планеті досліджують **той COVID-19** як тільки можуть: заморожують його, нагрівають, поміщають в невагомість, на різні предмети тощо. //https://novadoba.com.ua/60988-virus-to-ne-lyshe-pro-lyudey-ale-y-pro-tvaryn.html
>
> Це ж скільки треба скинути попів з неба, щоб задобрити **того ковіда**? //https://twitter.com/VTsvil/status/1247953460609388548
>
> довго вирощували там ціли [цілі] колонії **того ковіду**, аж поки вже з-за кордонів не почало до курцистів лунати — шо ж ви там і з ким бабло колотите, з руссо-туристо петровими-бошировими також, і людей заражаєте? //https://forum.pravda.com.ua/index.php?topic=1072879.msg23918277#msg23918277
>
> Та у нас **того Ковіду** сотні тисяч. //https://forum.pravda.com.ua/index.php?topic=1075184.msg24017589#msg24017589
>
> І будемо мерти, від **того ковіду**, як мухи від дихлофосу. //https://instashowe.com/media-video/B9W2bKjI0av
>
> Чи те, що ці всі загадкові пневмонії, якими масово хворіють і зараз, не є **тим ковідом**? //https://censor.net.ua/ua/comments/locate/8/3194248/73698724
>
> Оце аби лише паніку сіяти та клікбейт підвищувати, як із **тим ковідом**, хвахівці… //https://www.epravda.com.ua/news/2020/03/10/657895/
>
> Мабуть переболів, я **тим ковідом**. //http://www.poetryclub.com.ua/getpoem.php?id=874721
>
> …І якби в нас був саме він, то ми б вже перехворіли **тим Ковідом**. //https://bitter-onion.livejournal.com/3220862.html?thread=28868990#t28868990
>
> Ото вони за **тим ковідом** і пруться навмисно, це ж як самим богом дано. //https://forum.pravda.com.ua/index.php?topic=1074249.msg23973373#msg23973373
>
> За що "воювати" з **тим ковідом-19**???? //http://cocinalat.gametaz.info/video/WxpnKOyWEvE
>
> Так чи інакше **цим ковідом** ПОВИННІ перрехворіти або бути провакциновані ВСІ. //https://rastych.com/index.php?topic=1072328.msg23907445#msg23907445
>
> Перестаньте вже замилювати око **тим ковідом**!!! //https://ukcharts.info/what/kn_VkofLqHbe3Iw-vipusk-tsn-16-45-za-4-travna-2020-roku
>
> Що за дурниця, задовбали вже з **тим ковідом**!!! //https://trshow.info/watch/-1NVPVwGLW8/likarka-ludmila-minova-rozpovila-pro-najbil-s-posireni-simptomi-koronavirusu.html
>
> Щоб ви всі захворіли **тим ковідом**!!! //https://th-cam.com/video/H8tVj3V4zJ8/s-ogodni-verhovna-rada-golosuvatime-za-stvorenna-fondu-borot-bi-z-koronavirusom-prame-vklucenna.html

А ще крім «той ковід» можна пошукати «ваш ковід», «небезпечний ковід» й інші словосполучення.

Answer (score -3):

У жіночому, адже абревіатура розшифровується "Коронавірусна хвороба 2019" (Coronavirus disease 2019).

Comment: _COVID ⟨ковід⟩_ розшифровується не як _коронавірусна хвороба_, а як _coronavirus disease ⟨коронавайрус дізіс⟩_ — це з граматичного погляду зовсім не те саме, що _коронавірусна хвороба_ (при цьому, мені здається, більшість його подумки навіть не розшифровує). Тому мені не здається це доречним аргументом.

Comment: "_розшифровується не як коронавірусна хвороба, а як coronavirus disease ⟨коронавайрус дізіс⟩_" **Поки що** не погоджуюсь, прошу детальніше пояснити, чому Ви вважаєте, що саме так. Зараз ще раз розбираю [способи перекладу абревіатур](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6072/51) (додав там уточнювальне запитання) і створив питання про [загальні правила узгодження абревіатур](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6265/51).

Comment: А як «COVID» може розшифровуватися в «коронавірусна хвороба»? «D» — це від «disease». Від «хвороба» було б, наприклад, «ковіх» чи «ковіхв».

Comment: Гаразд, дякую. Наразі подальший аналіз і обговорення маю відкласти на потім.

Comment: Без авторитетних джерел така відповідь - суб'єктивізм.