# У якому роді узгоджуються абревіатури?

Tags: скорочення, рід, узгодження-слів

Як перекладати абревіатури вже [спитали](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6072/51), але як їх узгоджувати? **Чи є загальні правила, за якими визначається рід абревіатури у реченні?** Мабуть, для іншомовних це залежить від способу перекладу, але як?

Питання виникло у процесі обговорення [узгодження COVID-19](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6262/51), це питання для обговорення загальних правил на противагу конкретному випадку.

Comment: Бачу, що тег називається скорочення, дещо пізніше розбиратимусь чи краще називати абревіатури скороченнями.